# De-serializing objects from a file in Java

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I have a file which contains multiple serialized objects of class XYZ. While serializing, the each XYZ object was appended to the file.

Now I need to read each object from the file, and I am able to read only the first object.

Any idea how I can read each object from the file and eventually store it into a List?

Comment: Could you please provide a code snippet which would illustrate the problem?

Comment: Were the objects all written in a single session (with a single `ObjectOutputStream` instance), or were there multiple sessions (creating, using, and closing an `ObjectOutputStream` for each)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the following:

```
List<Object> results = new ArrayList<Object>();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("cool_file.tmp");
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

try {
    while (true) {
        results.add(ois.readObject());
    }
} catch (OptionalDataException e) {
    if (!e.eof) 
        throw e;
} finally {
    ois.close();
}
```

Following up on Tom's brilliant comment, the solution for multiple `ObjectOutputStream`s would be,

```
public static final String FILENAME = "cool_file.tmp";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    String test = "This will work if the objects were written with a single ObjectOutputStream. " +
            "If several ObjectOutputStreams were used to write to the same file in succession, " +
            "it will not. – Tom Anderson 4 mins ago";

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(FILENAME);
        for (String s : test.split("\\s+")) {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(s);
        }
    } finally {
        if (fos != null)
            fos.close();
    }

    List<Object> results = new ArrayList<Object>();

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(FILENAME);
        while (true) {
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            results.add(ois.readObject());
        }
    } catch (EOFException ignored) {
        // as expected
    } finally {
        if (fis != null)
            fis.close();
    }
    System.out.println("results = " + results);
}
```

Comment: This will work if the objects were written with a single `ObjectOutputStream`. If several `ObjectOutputStream`s were used to write to the same file in succession, it will not.

Comment: @TomAnderson so true... Well, fixed.

Comment: We don't actually know that the objects were written separately yet. Your first answer might be perfectly correct!

Comment: I don't know if something has changed in the last 4 years, but it worked for me when I tried with several ObjectOutputStreams. Every time I wrote to the file, I made sure I was appending, like : fos = new FileOutputStream(FILENAME, true);

Answer (score 1):

You can't append ObjectOutputStreams to a file. They contain headers as well as the objects you wrote. Revise your technique.

Also your EOF detection is wrong. You should catch EOFException separately. OptionalDataException means something different entirely.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
  System.out.println("Nombre del archivo ?");
                  nArchivo= sc.next();
                  sc.nextLine();
                  arreglo=new ArrayList<SuperHeroe>();

                  try{

                         FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(nArchivo);
                         ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);

                        while(true){
                            arreglo.add((SuperHeroe) in.readObject());

                        }



                    }

                      catch(IOException i)
                      {
                         System.out.println("no hay mas elementos\n elementos cargados desde el archivo:" );

                         for(int w=0;w<arreglo.size();w++){
                          System.out.println(arreglo.get(w).toString());
                         }



                      }catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
                      {
                         System.out.println("No encontre la clase Estudiante !");
                         c.printStackTrace();

                         return;
                      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below mentioned code for handling end of file differently:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("E://sample.txt"));
    oos.writeObject(new Integer(5));
    oos.writeObject(new Integer(6));
    oos.writeObject(new Integer(7));
    oos.writeObject(new Integer(8));
    oos.flush();
    oos.close();

    ObjectInputStream ios = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("E://sample.txt"));
    Integer temp;
    try {
        while ((temp = (Integer) ios.readObject()) != null) {
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    } catch (EOFException e) {

    } finally {
        ios.close();
    }

}
```

It will write and read multiple integer objects from the file without throwing any exception.