# Reading multiple objects from file

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, java-io, eofexception

Is there a proper way of reading objects from file using the `ObjectInputStream`. The examples I've seen seems to rely on that exception is caught to end the reading. While it maybe works it does not seem to be a clean solution as in exception shouldn't really happen unless there's wrong in the code.

[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826834/de-serializing-objects-from-a-file-in-java)

Comment: If you know the number of objects in the file then write code that uses that information. If the file has an unknown number of objects then the `Exception` approach is the correct one. You could potentially write this information in the first object in the file...

Comment: @bmorris591 You would still have to deal with EOFException if the first object wasn't there, or the count was wrong, for example if the writing process didn't succeed in writing all the objects it intended to.

Comment: @EJP yes, certainly, but that _would_ be an exceptional case. I think the OP is objecting to using an `Exception` as a control flow statement.

Comment: @bmorris Actually the OP seems to think that 'exceptions shouldn't happen unless there's [something] wrong in the code', which is taking the 'principle' you mention to its logical, absurd, conclusion.

Comment: @EJP point taken. I still think it makes sense in this case to deal with reading data minus `Exception`s and handle them when there is something wrong _with the input_. But you are absolutely right, exceptions deal with movement off of the "happy flow" and do not indicate coding errors.

Comment: @bmorris The case when there is 'something wrong with the input' is not in general distinguishable from the case when there just isn't any more input. Redefining 'exceptional' so as to include one case and not the other isn't feasible.

Answer (score 0):

`EOFException` is thrown by the `readObject()` method to indicate end of stream. Ergo you must catch it to detect end of stream. QED. Never mind the exception police.

Comment: very boring, but sadly the only way I guess :/

Comment: I cannot understand this comment. What is 'boring' about catching an exception?

Comment: Catching exception is not boring. I was referring to that I have to catch exception when it has reached the end of file.

Comment: @starcorn Catching exceptions at end of file isn't boring either. If that's what the API designers have determined what you have to do, that's what you have to do. Nobody actually cares whether you find it boring or not.

Comment: If that's your opinion. Btw, calm down. I didn't say people should care about it :P

Comment: Thats not my 'opinion', it's an inescapable fact. It's *your* unsolicited opinion, that it's 'boring', that's the problem here. It doesn't agree with the designers of the API.

Comment: Let me rephrase it then. It is very unfortunate that the solution for it was the need to catch EOFException.

Comment: @starcom No other solution is possible. There is no out of band value that could have been returned.