# Reading serialized object from a file?

Tags: java

I want to write and read a serializable class from a object file. I can write this object to a file but I cannot seem to be able to read the object back in and write it to the console.

Neither one of these options works. I just want to read in the object as it was written to the object file.

Code Tried:

```
public void readBinary1() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream
                                      ("G:\\testobject.tmp"));
        input.readObject();

        System.out.println(new myClass());
    }

    public void readBinary1() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream
                                      ("G:\\testobject.tmp"));

        System.out.println(new myClass(input.readObject()));
    }
```

class:

```
class myClass implements Serializable {
    myClass() {}

    myClass(myClass b) {
       this.a = b.a;
       this.b = b.b;
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int a = 0;
    private int b = 100;
    private transient int c = 50;
}
```

Code Added:

```
    I had to add a toString to my class to do it the way that it was suggested to do. That seems to be the way that is easiest in the short run but I would rather write the object and then be able to read in the object with out having to use the toString. Is there a way that I can read in the object with one read and then be able to break the info apart with the .dot notation. Such as mc.variable1 and mc.variable2 and so on. I had to type cast the read object also before the code would compile.
```

There are couple of input and output streams that allow for the serialization of objects to a file. I am certain that there are different ways to wrap the classes for the read and was wondering also which way was the best way to create the read.

Comment: Try searching for this problem on stack overflow -- there are literally dozens of similar questions and answers.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293991/how-to-write-and-read-java-serialized-objects-into-a-file

Comment: You don't seem to understand you're reading a *serialized object* from the stream. `MyClass mc = (MyClass) input.readObject();`. Done.

Comment: And see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/objectstreams.html

Comment: I know that I am reading a serialized object. I think that it reads the whole object into the variable and then I have to break that information up into what I would want to do with it like write or print or whatever. If I read an object from a file it should read it all in at one time just like if I was reading one string from the file. It would read a string at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
myClass readedObject = (myClass) input.readObject();
System.out.println(readedObject);
```