# Write a string list to a file and retrieve it

Tags: java, string, list, file

How to write a list of strings to a file and then retrieve the list?Basically how do I write a small custom serializer and deserializer for this custom job.

Comment: I tried to implement something on the lines of a md5 hash, but it doesn't look efficient.

Comment: This question is too broad. Try narrowing it down by giving more details in the question rather than adding comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that is a case that serialization will do the work, as you pointed is trivial to select a separator that is not used on the string.
md5 clearly you cannot use it,becouse is a one way encripting, so you will not be able to obtain the list laster.
The other option if you don´t want to use serialization, is to convert each string in base64, and then keep a empty line as separator per example.

About serialization:

[How to write and read java serialized objects into a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293991/how-to-write-and-read-java-serialized-objects-into-a-file)