# What is the best approach to save realtime sensors data in JavaFX

Tags: java, logging, javafx

I've written a simple JavaFX application in which I read sensors data (light, temperature, humidity, ...) from serial port (I use Arduino) and now I want to store these data, but I don't know what is the best approach to do this. Could you help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's depends of what you want to do with these data, you have many options.

Per example, you can store them in a database
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-insert-records.htm

Or serialise them in a file
[How to write and read java serialized objects into a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293991/how-to-write-and-read-java-serialized-objects-into-a-file)