# Inspect a Java-serialized object without defining the object

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I want to introspect and amend a Java-serialized object (in a file). The file was serialized via `ObjectOutputStream` or similar. The file was not written by me and I don't have the class definition.

There is a [python module I found which can do this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/javaobj-py3/) but it's flaky. Is there a Java-native way of doing this?

There are [many questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826834/de-serializing-objects-from-a-file-in-java) and answers here about reading and writing serialized objects of **instances of classes that you have defined**, but I couldn't find anything about classes/objects external to the program.

Comment: What format is the file? xml? son? if your not sure post a link

Comment: Java serialized format: .ser. The default Java serialization format.

Comment: There's no standard Java way that I know of, because you're trying to do something *non-standard*. Look for 3rd party libs or write your own.

Comment: Take a look at this article http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072752/the-java-serialization-algorithm-revealed.html

Comment: If this is Java Object Serialization we're talking about, there is no easy way to do it. You would have to learn about the [Java Object Serialization Grammar for the Stream Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html#10258) and implement code to process it and get a sensible object out of it. Not a task for the faint of heart, I daresay!

Comment: It is in hexadecimal format, The article i posted about above describes parts of the format, if it is a small file when viewed through a hex viewer then try parsing it yourself using the article as a guide

Comment: Nobody does this because it is insane.  If you need to access the serialized form of a java object, then do not use java serialization.  Instead use xml, json, or something else.

Comment: It is not a hexadecimal format, it is a binary format.

Comment: Note that the serialization mechanism shouldn't be used anyway because of security issues.

Comment: @DwB I'm not doing this in production, but for pentesting. This is a legitimate usecase, as demonstrated by the fact there exists a Python module to do exactly this. I just hoped I wouldn't have to write my own thing and could leverage something in the ecosystem.

Comment: Welcome to the leading edge.  It appears that you get to write the utility.